# Parsing simple markup language with Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell

I'm trying to implement a very simple markup language.  I have an intermediate representation that looks like:

```
data Token = Str Text
           | Explode Text

type Rep = [Token]
```

So, the idea is to turn an arbitrary text of the form:

> The quick brown %%fox%% %%jumps%% over the %%lazy%% dog.

into:

```
[Str "The quick brown", Explode "fox", Explode "jumps", Str "over the", Explode "lazy", Str "dog"]
```

for further processing.  Also, it is important that we treat:

> %%fox%% %%jumps%%

differently than

> %%fox jumps%%

The latter should (Explode "fox jumps")

I tried to implement this using attoparsec, but I don't think I have the tools I need.  But I'm not so good with parsing theory (I studied math, not CS).  What kind of grammar is this?  What kind of parser combinator library should I use?  I considered using Parsec with a stateful monad transformer stack to keep track of the context.  Does that sound sensible?

Comment: Is it allowed to use `%%` over multiple words? `The %%quick brown%% fox` for example. Because if not, the standard library would be good enough for now. `parse = map toToken . words; isExplode s = isPrefixOf s "%%" && isSuffixOf s "%%" ; toToken s | isExplode s = Explode s | otherwise = Str s`

Comment: It is allowed, but I want to treat %%foo bar%% differently than %%foo%% %%bar%%.  Thanks for the question, I'll edit mine.

Comment: How can you get a literal `%%X%%` in the output, i.e. what input is required to get `[Str "%%X%%", Explode "X"]`?

Comment: Frerich: Good question.  It's not specified (i.e., it doesn't really matter if those Tokens are ever emitted).

Answer (score 1):

You can take the cheap and easy way, without a proper parser. The important thing to recognise is that this grammar is actually fairly simple – it has no recursion or such. It is just a flat listing of `Str`s and `Explode`s.

## The easy way

So we can start by breaking the string down into a list containing the text and the separators as separate values. We need a data type to separate the separators (`%%`) from actual text (everything else.)

```
data ParserTokens = Sep | T Text
```

### Breaking it down

Then we need to break the list into its constituents.

```
tokenise = intersperse Sep . map T . Text.splitOn "%%"
```

This will first split the string on `%%`, so in your example it'll become

```
["The quick brown ","fox"," ","jumps"," over the ","lazy"," dog."]
```

then we `map T` over it, to turn it from a `[Text]` to a `[ParserTokens]`. Finally, we `intersperse Sep` over it, to reintroduce the `%%` separators but in a shape that's easier to deal with. The result is, in your example,

```
[T "The quick brown ",Sep,T "fox",Sep,T " ",Sep,T "jumps",Sep,T " over the ",Sep,T "lazy",Sep,T " dog."]
```

### Building it up

With this done, all that remains is parsing this thing into the shape you want it. Parsing this amounts to finding the 1-2-3 punch of Sep–T "something"–Sep and replacing it with `Explode "something"`. We write a recursive function to do this.

```
construct [] = []
construct (T s : rest) = Str s : construct rest
construct (Sep : T s : Sep : rest) = Explode s : construct rest
construct _ = error "Mismatched '%%'!"
```

This converts `T s` to `Str s` and the combination of separators and a `T s` into an `Explode s`. If the pattern matching fails, it's because there were a stray separator somewhere, so I've just set it to crash the program. You might want better error handling there – such as wrapping the result in `Either String` or something similar.

With this done, we can create the function

```
parseTemplate = construct . tokenise
```

and in the end, if we run your example through parseTemplate, we get the expected result

```
[Str "The quick brown ",Explode "fox",Str " ",Explode "jumps",Str " over the ",Explode "lazy",Str " dog."]
```

Answer (score 0):

For such simple parser even Attoparsec seems to be overkill:

```
parse = map (\w -> case w of 
              '%':'%':expl -> Explode $ init $ init expl
              str -> Str str) . words
```

Of course, this code needs some sanity checks for `Explode` case.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't handle whitespace the way you specified, but it should get you on the right track.

```
parseMU = zipWith ($) (cycle [Str,Explode]) . splitps where
  splitps :: String -> [String]
  splitps [] = [[]]
  splitps ('%':'%':r) = [] : splitps r
  splitps (c:r) = let
    (a:r') = splitps r
    in ((c:a):r')
```